# Have a SVN checkout location connected to Codeplex and propagate updates to another develpment location connected to another SVN repository

Tags: windows, svn, replicate

I would like to checkout a read only SVN projects (e.g. from Codeplex) to a folder on my local disk, open the solution (let's say I am getting Dotnetnuke and open it's solution, add some projects to the solution and possibly changing some files, previously making them writable.
I want to regularly update the changes coming from Codeplex and do code mergers to preserver my changes).

However I would like to copy all the files in this checkout location to another "developer" location where I would play extensively with the source code and have my local SVN repository to preserve history and allow other developers to do check ins/outs. I should be able to use TortoiseSVN from Windows explorer or Visual Studio SVN Add-on to do check ins/outs.

So check outs from Codeplex to the first location would be an intermediate location from which I would like to update
a development area in another location that will be connected to Read/Write SVN repository on my local machine.

So how to make updates/synchronizations between first and second location (direction is from first to second location).
Can I use Tortoise SVN to move changes from first location to second (after SVN update from Codeplex).

Since I am using GIT and Mercurial clients how would I propagate changes to my Development SVN location.
I would prefer solution that would work across source version software.
Tx,
Rad

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVN switch to switch between repositories, although that could be tricky thing to do...

Wouldn't adding the Codeplex' repository as an external to your R/W repository do the thing? See:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: Would Switch allow me to do the merging inside Visual Studio. I know I can use Export from local version, but that would override my changes. I will check both Switch and External.
Tx

Comment: Since I can have some intermediate changes in my first location it seems that I need to treat that location as a originating repository and not Codeplex repository. Is this possible: to get updates and to the merging from a local working folder (first location) in the second (development working version)?

Comment: I can obviously create yet another Repository to hold Codeplex changes (a sort of replication on demand) and possibly use Switch or Relocate from my Development working folder